# Scaling a PDF image for NSStatusItem image

Tags: swift, macos, statusbar, appkit

I'm trying to create a macOS app with a status bar item that uses a PDF rather than PNG image, however when I use that image it's overscaled and the entire status item is black. I can't find a way to scale the image so that it fits with the rest of the mac status bar items.

#### Icon

- [Font Awesome](https://fontawesome.com/icons/globe?style=solid)

  - (I can't attach a pdf so you will need to convert it manually)

#### Assets.xcassets

[image: image of scode showing the pdf icon of a globe]

#### AppDelegate.swift

```swift
import Cocoa

@NSApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {

    let statusItem = NSStatusBar.system.statusItem(withLength:NSStatusItem.squareLength)

    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {
        // Insert code here to initialize your application
        if let button = statusItem.button {
          button.image = NSImage(named:NSImage.Name("status-logo"))
          button.action = #selector(printQuote(_:))
        }
    }

    @objc func printQuote(_ sender: Any?) {
      let quoteText = "Never put off until tomorrow what you can do the day after tomorrow."
      let quoteAuthor = "Mark Twain"

      print("\(quoteText) — \(quoteAuthor)")
    }

    func applicationWillTerminate(_ aNotification: Notification) {
        // Insert code here to tear down your application
    }
}
```

#### Expectation

[image: A picture of the icon]

#### Reality

[image: A screenshot showing a black square for my icon alongside other status bar items]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should resize your pdf so that it fits inside `statusItem`'s button like this:

```
    guard let logo = NSImage(named: NSImage.Name("status-logo")) else { return }

    let resizedLogo = NSImage(size: NSSize(width: 18, height: 18), flipped: false) { (dstRect) -> Bool in
        logo.draw(in: dstRect)
        return true
    }
```

Then set `button.image = resizedLogo`